# Knocking noise every morning, no appliances and no sprinkler

Tags: plumbing, noise

Recently had a knocking noise the last two days. We have nothing in the house right now and the sprinklers/AC are off. Any ideas what it may be?

https://youtu.be/aTqmarGdK6s?si=iEkZbiJ2lwKZHZT7

Comment: Does it happen at around the same time of day each time?

Comment: Have you tried answering the door?

Comment: First step is to find where it's coming from. Then figure out what's in that area. Heating system or hot water  pipes that might be undergoing thermal expansion? Are you certain it's inside the house?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the house except a near-empty steel paint can? The top or bottom is popping like a canning jar as the temperature changes. I have one in the next room that does that on summer mornings as the house heats up.

Comment: That's what it sounds like to me.